# Combine two lists in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, merge, dataframe

I have two lists with different structure:

```
listA <- list(c("a","b","c"), c("d","e"))
listB <- list(0.05, 0.5)

listA
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "d" "e"

listB
[[1]]
[1] 0.05

[[2]]
[1] 0.5
```

I have an idea of how to use looping to combine both lists in a dataframe that looks like the one below but I'm sure that there is a more efficient way of doing this.

```
data.frame(A = c("a","b","c","d","e"), B = c(rep(0.05,3), rep(0.5,2)))
  A    B
1 a 0.05
2 b 0.05
3 c 0.05
4 d 0.50
5 e 0.50
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is another option:

```
do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, A=listA, B=listB))

#   A    B
# 1 a 0.05
# 2 b 0.05
# 3 c 0.05
# 4 d 0.50
# 5 e 0.50
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe there is a more elegant way that keeps the class `numeric` of `list2`'s elements... But this one works as well

```
df <- do.call(rbind,mapply(cbind, listA, listB))
df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df[,2] <- as.numeric(df[,2])
```

**EDIT** Way better is Matthew Plourde's solution using `Map` aka `mapply(data.frame, A=listA, B=listB, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Answer (score 4):

If looking for a `tidyverse` solution, here is the analogue to the accepted answer. Using the `dfr` suffix to the `map` function family enables a very simple solution which should also be faster than `do.call("rbind")`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
listA <- list(c("a","b","c"), c("d","e"))
listB <- list(0.05, 0.5)

map2_dfr(listA, listB, ~ tibble(A = .x, B = .y))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   A         B
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a      0.05
#> 2 b      0.05
#> 3 c      0.05
#> 4 d      0.5 
#> 5 e      0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: best solution because there are no ugly row names!

Comment: @ Calum You can you explain the meaning of .x and .y? Which letters beside .x and .y should I use if I have lists A,B,C and D instead of only A and B? Thank you!

Comment: @user2165379 see the documentation for map2; .x and .y are placeholders for the first and second arguments to the function. you'll want pmap for arbitrary argument number functions and ..1, ..2 placeholders.

Comment: @ Calum You thank you. I will look into pmap.

Answer (score 3):

Another way without using do.call:

```
cbind(data.frame(listA), data.frame(listB))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer this:

```
do.call(rbind,
        Map(function(...) setNames(cbind.data.frame(...), 
                                   c("A", "B")), 
            listA, listB))
#  A    B
#1 a 0.05
#2 b 0.05
#3 c 0.05
#4 d 0.50
#5 e 0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(1:length(listA),
               function(i)
                 data.frame(A=unlist(listA[i]),
                            B=unlist(listB[i]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This places the index and renames the columns appropriately:

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, Map('c', listA, listB))
colnames(df)[1] <- "A"
colnames(df)[2] <- "B"
```